# Asking a question similar to a community wiki on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, questions, community-wiki

Recently, I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662714/the-definitive-c-video-guide-and-list) question on Stack Overflow which has been put on hold. A more experienced user commented "Did you discuss your idea on Meta, first?" since this type of questions is apparently not suited for the site.

Given that [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) exists as a community wiki, is there a way to suggest that a community wiki be created as well for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662714/the-definitive-c-video-guide-and-list)?

Comment: If you take the time and read through the different posts that discuss that question, you will find there is a lot of controversy about this kind of question (and that that particular one has been closed/reopened a good number of times). It mostly remains as it was extremely popular (even if no longer suitable) and is actively maintained by the C++ community on the site.

Comment: So the creation of a similar wiki, about videos this time, is out of the question

Answer (score 7):

Did you actually read the similar post? If you did, you would have seen:

> This question has historical significance, but is not a good example of an appropriate question. Read and learn from this post, but please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions.

If it was posted today, it would be closed and deleted very quickly, but since it was posted back when these types of questions were allowed, and the C++ community now maintains and moderates it, an exception was made.

Comment: Thnx, I will go back and delete the question